# One-to-many. Do I need to break association before removing the owner side of association?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

Look at the example:

I am using Spring Boot and JPA.

I have two entities `TaskGroup` and `Task`.

```
public class TaskGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group")
    private Set<Task> tasks;
  }

public class Task {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
        private int id;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn("group_id")
        private TaskGroup group;
      }
```

I want to delete `task` belonging to a `group` ( associated with `group` ). My question is, should I break the association between this `task` and `group` first? In other words:

```
task.setGroup(null);
repository.deleteById(taskId);
```

or just

repository.deleteById(taskId);

?

Comment: both work fine,

Comment: I know but it doesn't mean that both are correct. I think the latter option may give me some trouble in future application development but I might be wrong

Comment: it doesn't cause any problem. in both the cases the query going to the database is same.
when the same thing is happening in both the cases what problem are you expecting.

Comment: task.setGroup()  has importance when you are saving or updating task, that time JPA has to associate the relationship based on this.  But when you are deleting the task - it doesn't have any impact.